# How to i install my video driver for nvidia geforce 610M on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiz, video, resolution

I've just installed ubuntu on my laptop and noticed that my nvidia driver wasnt installed. So I installed nvidia-current with the terminal command sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
but now my display only has the 640p resolution and i cant seem to undo anything. 
I even tried sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current. it uninstalls but nothing changes and the resolution remains unchangable in the Display menu.

I tried to reset unity with the terminal command sudo unity -reset , but when i do that my screen flickers and compiz crashes. For me to restore compiz is to restart my computer.

Can anyone give me and idea where to look elsewhere for problems because im getting pretty lost here and working in 640p isnt ideal

thanks in advance,

Funonly

Answer (score 0):

When you install the nVidia driver, it also installs nVidia's own display management software, which takes over the job of the built in Display settings.

Just open the Unity menu (the Super, or "Windows" key, or click the Ubuntu icon in the top of the application launcher bar) and start typing in "nvidia". It should find the nVidia display manager for you to open and adjust your settings as needed.